# How to paint regions of a map with visually different colors

Tags: procedural-generation, color

I'm learning some concepts of procedural content generation. Now I'm generating a map with regions and each region has a diferent colors generated in a pseudo-random way.

My problem right now is that most of times (more probably when more regions exists), some regions has colors that are visually similar. 
[image]

I want to control that adjacent colors are visually different, but still with some random component. What make colors different?

Comment: Similar question on different colors set - https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46463

Comment: Yes, but that question is not based on the fact that colors are procedurally generated. This changes conditions

Answer (score 5):

You could now go really deep into color theory to answer the question of what exactly makes two colors visually distinct. RGB is a color system for machines which doesn't map linearly to human perception. So if you want a *really good* formula, then it can get amazingly complex. And if you want your game to be  accessible for people with various forms of  [color blindness](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-colorblind-issues), then you might have to offer some completely different alternative formulas.

But a quick-and-dirty solution could be to simply look at their respective difference of their R, G and B components and add them up. So if you have the colors `col1` and `col2`, then you could calculate their difference with

```
abs(col1.r - col2.r) + 
abs(col1.g - col2.g) +
abs(col1.b - col2.b)
```

But now that we have this formula, what do we do if our algorithm placed two very similar colors next to each other? We could change one of them to a random other color, but now it might be too similar to one of its *other* neighbors. So changing one color could cause a ripple effect affecting all the other colors.

One solution I could think of would be to create four different color palettes 1 to 4. Make sure that none of the colors in one palette is visually close to a color in a different palette (you can have visually close colors in the same palette, though). Then pick colors from these palettes at random according to this schema:

```
12121212
34343434
12121212
34343434
```

Or in technical terms:

- If X is even and Y is even, use palette  1
- If X is odd and Y is even, use palette  2
- If X is even and Y is odd, use palette  3
- If X is odd and Y is odd, use palette  4

This means that all neighbors of a tile will be from a different palette. And because no color has a similar color in a different palette, you will never have two visually similar colors next to each other.